# Should methods in a class be classmethod by default?

Tags: python, oop

I was just working on a large class hierarchy and thought that probably all methods in a class should be classmethods by default.

I mean that it is very rare that one needs to change the actual method for an object, and whatever variables one needs can be passed in explicitly. Also, this way there would be lesser number of methods where people could change the object itself (more typing to do it the other way), and people would be more inclined to be "functional" by default.

But, I am a *newb* and would like to find out the flaws in my idea (if there are any :).

Comment: Your premise is faulty. What makes you think that? If it's not a instance method, just make it a module-level function.

Comment: Sorry, I am having a hard time following what you are trying to say. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I was just wondering why it is that methods in python , by default take the object itself as an input instead of the class. Since most of the time you really dont need to set a state on the object itself, for example I am working with a database class and I defined a method that gives me some statistics about the data, it need only some of the data and not really the complete object which might be expensive to initialize, so why not keep classmethods as default? but I guess this might just be happening in my current usecase.

Comment: Most methods *I* write need access to the instance data, that is the point of a class. The instance data is not re-built every time you call a method, the instance already is present in memory, and `self` is but a reference to that existing instance. If you are writing methods that mostly *do not* need access to the instance, then you should just use functions instead.

Answer (score 4):

Having classmethods as a default is a well-known but outdated paradigm.  It's called Modular Programming.  Your classes become effectively modules this way.

The Object-Oriented Paradigm (OOP) is mostly considered superior to the Modular Paradigm (and it is younger).  The main difference is exactly that parts of code are associated by default to a group of data (called an object) — and thus not classmethods.

It turns out in practice that this is much more useful.  Combined with other OOP architectural ideas like inheritance this offers directer ways to represent the models in the heads of the developers.

Using object methods I can write abstract code which can be used for objects of various types; I don't have to know the type of the objects while writing my routine.  E. g. I can write a `max()` routine which compares the elements of a list with each other to find the greatest.  Comparing then is done using the `>` operator which is effectively an object method of the element (in Python this is `__gt__()`, in C++ it would be `operator>()` etc.).  Now the object itself (maybe a number, maybe a date, etc.) can handle the comparison of itself with another of its type.  In code this can be written as short as

```
a > b   # in Python this calls a.__gt__(b)
```

while with only having classmethods you would have to write it as

```
type(a).__gt__(a, b)
```

which is much less readable.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer, i'll look up some lit on modular programming and see why it became outdated. I'll vote you up when I earn enough karma :)

Answer (score 1):

If the method doesn't access any of an object's state, but is specific to that object's class, then it's a good candidate for being a classmethod.

Otherwise if it's more general, then just use a function defined at module level, no need to make it belong to a specific class.

I've found that classmethods are actually pretty rare in practice, and certainly not the default. There should be plenty of good code out there (on e.g. github) to get examples from.

Comment: +1 it's totally in the hands of the developer and there is no general answer to give. But often there's no need for classmethods.

Comment: Putting a routine as a `classmethod` inside a class normally states a logic connection of this routine to this class.  If it is accessing any of the class variables, this would be a strong hint on such a connection.  But also if it is not accessing anything of this class but is otherwise logically connected, it should be placed inside the class, then probably as a `staticmethod`.